# Change SelectInput based on the selection of another one in React-Admin

Tags: javascript, react-admin

My React-Admin UI has a `create` resource that has a SimpleForm with a couple selection boxes.

Those selection boxes, **Location** and **Time Zone**, are [decorated with](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SelectInput.html#using-in-a-referenceinput) ReferenceInput, so as to pull their selectable values from api endpoints:

```
<Create>
    <SimpleForm>
        ... 
        <ReferenceInput 
            label="Location"
            source="id"
            reference="locations"
        >
            <SelectInput 
                optionText={choice => `${choice.location}, ${choice.state}`} />
        </ReferenceInput>

       <ReferenceInput 
           label="Time Zone"
           source="id"
           reference="timezones"
       >
           <SelectInput optionText="timezonecode" />
       </ReferenceInput>
       ...
```

The user chooses the values for each before submitting the form.

But is there some way to set up SimpleForm to tie these 2 input selections together?

Specifically, I'd like to have the **Time Zone** field change accordingly when the user changes the **Location** selection.

The user should actually be able to override this if they go back and change the **Time Zone** selection. So this would be a one-way connection in that when **Location** is changed that should trigger a **Time Zone** change, but not the other way around.

(The *Location* database table that creates the **Location** endpoint does have a *timezone_id* column that references the *timezone* table's *id* column. It's just not clear to me yet how to tie these select boxes together in a React-Admin form.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use react-hook-form's `useWatch` hook, as explained in the react-admin documentation (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs). I suppose you want to use the location as a *filter*. for the timezone options, so this would give something like that:

```
const TimeZoneInput = (props) => {
  const location = useWatch({ name: 'id' });
  return (
       <ReferenceInput 
           label="Time Zone"
           source="id"
           reference="timezones"
           filter={{ id }}
       >
           <SelectInput optionText="timezonecode" />
       </ReferenceInput>
);
```

More info on `useWatch` in the react-hook-form documentation: https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch

Comment: This looks promising. Unfortunately, I get `Uncaught TypeError: methods is null`. Possibly caused by version incompatibilities due to my using an old React-Admin version (2.9.4) - maybe similar to this: https://github.com/react-hook-form/devtools/issues/79. I need to find a workaround. But I'm accepting the above, as that (or FormDataConsumer, also described at the link you provided) seems like the right approach.

Comment: Indeed, for react-admin 2.9, the method is different because it's using redux-form instead of react-hook-form. It's documented here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs